# Unity: Gallery Images Random are repeating

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, random

I have a gallery Image where i have 4 UI images choose random sprite form my sprite array and assign it after a random time. My issue is that my 4 UI images

Answer (score 0):

Your getting a random ítem each time you call MakeRandomNumber.
You need to shuffle your list of images and when you make full loop, shuffle again.
I can't test the code but sure you can fix if there are a Little error.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Gallery : MonoBehaviour
{

public float timer;
public Sprite[] gallerySprites;
public Image currentImage;
public int ImagesLoopIndex = 0;

public int newRandomNummer;
int lastRandomNumber;
int min = 0;
int max;

public Gallery[] galleries;

public List<int> val = new List<int>();

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    ShuffleImagesList();
    max = gallerySprites.Length;
    timer = MakeRandomNumber(8, 18);
}

private void ShuffleImagesList()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < galleries.lenght -1; i++) 
    {
         Gallery[] temp = galleries[i];
         int randomIndex = Random.Range(i, galleries.lenght-1);
         galleries[i] = galleries[randomIndex];
         galleries[randomIndex] = temp;
     }

}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    timer -= Time.deltaTime;

    if (timer <= 0)
    {


        StartCoroutine(fadeImages());
        timer = MakeRandomNumber(8, 18);


    }

}

IEnumerator fadeImages()
{
    if (ImagesLoopIndex >= galleries.lenght)
    {
        ShuffleImagesList();
        ImagesLoopIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        currentImage.CrossFadeAlpha(0, 1f, false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        currentImage.CrossFadeAlpha(1, 1f, false);
        currentImage.sprite = gallerySprites[ImagesLoopIndex];
        ImagesLoopIndex = ImagesLoopIndex +1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey, it doesnt work, yes there was errors but i fixed them but it's still duplicating. any ideas?

Comment: @loue13 `currentImage.sprite = gallerySprites[MakeRandomNumber(0, max)];` should be `currentImage.sprite = gallerySprites[ImagesLoopIndex];` to fix it. Also the else code should run every time and not be in a else.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to pull a random image from a list and display it in some number of Image objects.  You need to have the list of sprites (the images) in a separate object and then a `Sprite GetSprite()` method which only returns one that has not been sent yet.

One way would be to have 2 arrays `Sprite[] NotUsed` and `Sprite[] Used` and when you pull a random one from the NotUsed one, remove it and add it to the other list. This ensures you will only return a unique sprite in the list.

Hope this is what you were looking for.